# Easy points: Expression 4 Studio is the final release, eh?

Tags: expression-blend

I just wanna make sure I ain't downloading a RC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Expression 4 Studio is the latest version.

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/